# Can't add system.media.imaging even after adding PresentationCore and WindowsBase

Tags: c#

I've just installed C# Visual Express 2010.

The project is created under Console Application.

Any ideas? Thanks.

I'm trying to copy a range in excel and save it as a image file.

---

I have both PresentationCore and WindowsBase in my References.
But I'm still getting this error.

"Error  1   The type or namespace name 'Imaging' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Media' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

---

Target Framwork is .NET Framework 3.5. It's still not working.

Comment: No idea. Updated with more info. Is there anymore info that you need?

Comment: The same issue discuss here. Check whether this helps http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/windowswic/thread/fdfff143-c1ae-41cd-bbeb-8ff6c1c879ec

Answer (score 0):

On versions of Visual Studio 2010, the default framework used for console applications is `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`.  The classes you're trying to use are probably not available for this version of the framework.

You need to change your project so it targets the full, `.NET Framework 4` (or at least `.NET Framework 3.5`).

I don't have the express version installed to use as a reference but in regular versions of Visual Studio, you can do this by:

1. Right clicking on your project in the solution explorer and select `Properties`.
2. Under the `Application` tab, change the `Target Framework` from `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` to `.NET Framework 4`.
3. Save.

You'll probably have to reopen your project so the changes could take effect.  The assemblies should then be available to you.

Comment: It even sounds like you've actually targeted `.NET Framework 2` or lower.  The assemblies should be available in (client profile) 3.5 and above.